# How can I save the segmentation result of segnet

Tags: caffe, semantic-segmentation

```
scipy.misc.toimage(rgb, cmin=0.0, cmax=255).save(IMAGE_FILE+'_segnet.png')
```

In the file `test_segmentation_camvid`, how should I define the `IMAGE_FILE` and save the prediction results?

Answer (score 0):

IMAGE_FILE is just a variable that would be the name of the saved image
you can do something like

```
IMAGE_FILE="new_image"
scipy.misc.toimage(rgb, cmin=0.0, cmax=255).save(IMAGE_FILE+'_segnet.png')
```

and the image that would be saved will be under the name `new_image_segnet.png`